# Funções WHERE SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
$qrysel = "select * from won_auctions w left join registration r on w.userid=r.id where xxx;
```

Essa query vai mostrar uma lista de usuários da tabela **won_auctions** e pegar o nome do usuário na tabela **registration**.

A ideia é que ele verifique quantos registros tem cada usuário na tabela **won_auctions** durante o mês atual, e o total.

Preciso também ordenar para exibir os que tem mais registros por primeiro, para o mês atual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS qtd_reg,
    w.*,
    r.*
FROM
    won_auctions w
LEFT JOIN registration r ON w.userid = r.id
WHERE
    YEAR([campo_data]) = '2017' -- ANO DO FILTRO
    AND MONTH([campo_data]) = '11' -- MES DO FILTRO;
GROUP BY [user_id]
ORDER BY qtd_reg
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa é uma opção, como você não deu muitos detalhes sobre a sua arquitetura e nem como estão suas tabelas, eu usei nomes genéricos:

```
select * from (
 select r.username, count(w.registros) as contagem
 from won_auctions w 
 left join registration r 
  on w.userid=r.id where data >= 'inicio do mes' and data <= 'final do mes'
 group by r.userid
) a
order by a.contagem desc
```

Comment: Bom dia! Tu tem skype para gente conversar sobre esse problema?